# Google Map static image with multiple paths

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to draw a static Image between every source point to one destination point using Google map static image api.

e.g. we have multiple source points,  S = {s1,s2,.....sn} and one destination point D = {d1}.

I consulted official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Paths) by Google. 
But they are passing only one 'path' attribute.

How should I do this?

Comment: Should you try **Encoded Polylines**

Comment: Would you share a screenshot, what you want to achieve specifically

Comment: How can i provide screeshot @ParagBhayani. Actually there are n sources and 1 destination marked to Google map and i want to draw paths between them.

Comment: @ParagBhayani can u pls re post the solution that u posted yesterday. I found that relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you can draw multiple paths using the Static Maps API, but you could build a path that connects the points you're looking for by joining them all together: `S1|D1|S2|D1|S3|...` and revisiting that central destination.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?path=40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963|40.737102,-73.990318|40.735781,-74.003571|40.737102,-73.990318|40.731690,-73.977849&size=512x512

Comment: But the path straight line not actual path

Answer (score 10):

You can create multiple paths using Google static maps.

The same way you create multiple markers:

?path=...&path=...

Example
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=1200x400&path=color:red|weight:2|-35.7297745,174.1291597|-35.744471441965,174.37021155622&path=color:blue|weight:2|-35.7297745,174.3291597|-35.662336702516,174.28593575266

Answer (score 1):

Use Maps static API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro

Here you can pass multiple **path** variables. You need to make sure it is a closed path. First and last property in the path

> &path=color:0x000000FF|fillcolor:0x7f97b2|weight:1|40.6697067853831,-73.7912202983732|40.669652659255,-73.7912323557795|40.6695985336754,-73.7912444138854|40.6696476714302,-73.7915990162982|40.6697557235014,-73.7915734470598|40.6697067853831,-73.7912202983732&path=.....

Also you can use encode polylines (refer documentation) to overcome the character size restriction

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.7908406,-73.97359489999997&size=426x321&zoom=17&maptype=roadmap&style=element:geometry|color:grey&style=element:labels.icon|visibility:off&style=feature:road|visibility:on|color:grey&path=color:black|fillcolor:0x013a6f|weight:1|enc:w}}wF|}nbM@Ap@b@m@jBq@c@j@iB&&path=color:black|fillcolor:0x32c5f4|weight:1|enc:i_~wFx|nbMp@b@k@hBq@e@j@gB&

Answer (score 0):

@mohit you mean this?

```
var routes = [{origin: ..., destination: ...}, {origin: ..., destination: ...}, {origin: ..., destination: ...}];
var rendererOptions = {
    preserveViewport: true,         
    suppressMarkers:true,
    routeIndex:i
};
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

routes.each(function(route){
    var request = {
    origin: route.origin,
    destination: route.destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    console.log(result);

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
    });
});
```

Or this may help you -> http://jsfiddle.net/fjUqK/

Comment: this example generates maps with more than one location. But my problem is generation of map **IMAGE** with one destination and multiple source points through Google static image api which take only one **path** parameter. Basically i want to pass multiple discontinuous path attribute value.

Comment: Hmm, just for curiosity I want to know why you want it as an image?

Comment: once the map is drawn with multiple sources and one destination, i want it to be downloaded on the client side in the form of image. thats why i want image